HttpContext.Current.Session returns Null in .NET Framework v4.8
I am moving my .NET solution to a new server that uses VS2022 and .NET Framework 4.8. Originally my codebase was targetting .NET 4.5.2 (now eol) version.
So when I moved a copy of the codebase and opened the solution, VS asked for updating the codebase to .NET 4.8 and that's all updated. Once updating the codebase, session setting in web.config:
<system.web>
    <sessionState timeout="40" mode="InProc"/>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.8"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
</system.web>

The GetSession method has a line of code:
HttpContext.Current.Session.Contents[Parameter].ToString();

which now returns NULL and errors with

Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Code:
 public string GetSession(string Parameter)
 {
     try
     {
         return HttpContext.Current.Session.Contents[Parameter].ToString();
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
         return "";
     }
 }


The exact same codebase works perfectly fine in the old server with .NET framework 4.5.2. Any help on how to fix this?

UPDATE:
the getsession gets called in the page_load event of the master file:
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    try
    {
        if (IsPostBack == false)
        {
            if (sss.GetSession(xxx_Session_Type.UserRole) != null)
            {
                UserRole();
            }
        }

        if (sss.GetSession(xxx_Session_Type.UserID) != "")
        {
            divLogin.Visible = true;
            lblWelcome.Text = sss.GetSession(xxx_Session_Type.UserName).ToString();
            //UpdateConfirmItSync();
        }
        else
        {
            divLogin.Visible = false;
        }
    }


Is that method being called from a new Task or thread?

So HttpContext.Current.Session.Contents[Parameter] is reading from the session state. But if this is new, that parameter in the session state is likely not there. So isn't this doing what you expect?

What happens if you step over the exception?

Put a breakpoint on that line. Run to it. When you hit it, go to Immediate Window and run ?HttpContext.Current.Session. What is the result?

Is Session itself null? Or just the value returned by contents?

what is class "sss.". Is this a static class, or is a instance being creating, and when/where/how is this class being created? And why not just use Session[] right in the code? Failing to see how you saving any typing here?

Maybe check wat actually is null?
Can also add some null checks here like so:
e.g. HttpContext?.Current?.Session?.Contents[Parameter]

ok sorry for the delayed reply. Session ID is present but the content returns null

So show us the code where that content is populated.

just paste this line in the web.config inside the <system.serviceModel> tag

<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />

